# Using stagePadding to separate items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h8kmove5/98/

I am trying to move the left and right items to the edge like so:

http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/stagepadding.html

But with 3 in total, instead of 7.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sync1 = $("#sync1");
  var sync2 = $("#sync2");

  sync1.owlCarousel({
    stagePadding: 50,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    items : 3,
    slideSpeed : 1000,
    navigation: true,
    pagination:false,
    responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#sync1 .item{
    background: #0c83e7;
    padding: 80px 0px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
#sync1 .item.noItem{
    background: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.min.css"></script>

<div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>6</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>7</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>8</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>9</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>10</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>11</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>12</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>13</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>14</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>15</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>16</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>17</h1></div>
  <div class="item"><h1>18</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BSMP Did you answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

After adding updated owl carousel js and css files, your code started working. I have also adjusted stagePadding value here.
Here's your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/h8kmove5/152/)

```
sync1.owlCarousel({
    stagePadding: 160,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:3
        }
    }
  });
```